# Does JBoss Developer Studio 7.1.1 work with an older JBoss App Server 5.0?

Tags: jboss

I am using JBoss Developer Studio 5.01 with JBoss App Server 5.0.  I want to upgrade the IDE to a later version but am concerned it might causes problems with an older app server.  Does anyone have any info on this?

Answer (score 0):

It support the same JBoss app server versions as in the past. It even have support for JBoss 3 :)